# AAR is missing my dependencies

Tags: android, aar

I have created a new project with only a module that is a library.

[image: android studio]

And here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
             'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+@aar'
}
```

If I build this project, it generates an `aar` file called `app-debug.aar` with 45kb. I was wondering why I need to include all dependencies on main project because if I include only the dependency of `app-debug.aar`, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Why I need to do this?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile ('org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+@aar')
    compile (name:'app-debug', ext:'aar')
}
```

Can I find a way that I don't need to include dependencies like altbeacon on main project (apk) and work only with `app-debug.aar` dependency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your application project:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile (name:'app-debug', ext:'aar') {
       transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question is described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/0ZAP8AVUZVw Basically, you need to create the aar using the command: gradle assemble

Comment: Hm..i'll try it..i've tried with transitive = true but no success.

Comment: Transitive is only for when you download the aar from a maven repository, not for local files. My mistake for not noticing that. If you build the aar with gradle assemble, and then include that one, it should contain all dependencies.

Comment: gradle assemble still creating an .aar file with 45kb (altbeacon has not been added to app-debug.aar)

Comment: They probably fixed it by then. Anyways, the Android Studio team stated, that aar files should not include external dependencies. When you upload the aar to a maven repository, the pom.xml will include the dependencies, and will get downloaded along with your library. Or you can add the library as a submodule to your project, which should also work. But not with packaging in an aar file.